# How to declare an Active Worksheet in a variable?

Tags: excel, vba, worksheet

I'm trying to keep a variable to the currently open worksheet in VBA. So far I have

```
 Dim Active As Worksheet
 Set Active = ActiveWorksheet
```

For some reason it gives me an error in the last line, saying Object required. My code opens a new worksheet with the data in the Active sheet, so I need a variable to hold my place in the currently active worksheet. Any idea why this isn't working correctly?

Comment: A good habit is to qualify the application globals with `Application.` - had you done that, IntelliSense would have told you what you were looking for.

Answer (score 11):

You need to use `ActiveSheet` instead of `ActiveWorksheet`

Answer (score 4):

I prefer not to use ActiveSheet in VBA because if further down the track you start writing code that uses multiple worksheets it can become confusing when trying to determine which is which.  I prefer the following

```
dim ws as Worksheet

ws = Thisworkbook.Worksheets(1)

OR

ws = Thisworkbook.Worksheets("worksheet name")
```

The only time I use Activesheet now is when I need some code to work on any worksheet regardless of what it contains, which is very rare.  In this case as has been stated above use:

```
dim ws as Worksheet

ws = Thisworkbook.Activesheet

OR

ws = Activesheet
```

Answer (score 0):

For me I like to directly speak to the worksheet I want to adress using Sheet("Worksheet").

So if you want to take an information form a particular sheet you can use this:

```
Dim ExampleWorksheet as Worksheet
Dim Example as Integer

Example = Sheets("ExampleWorksheet").Cells(x,y)
```

So you get rid of messing around with an active or not active worksheets.

Answer (score 0):

Dim bradouts As Workbook

Dim bradsht As Worksheet

If Right(myfile, 4) = ".xls" Then

```
Set bradouts = Workbooks.Open(myfolder & myfile)
```

End If

Set bradsht = bradouts.ActiveSheet <------

It shows error where i pointed arrow, can someone explain....i posted it here because its not allowing me to ask question directly.

Comment: This does not really answer the question. If you have a different question, you can ask it by clicking [Ask Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask). To get notified when this question gets new answers, you can [follow this question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/345661). Once you have enough [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation), you can also [add a bounty](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/set-bounties) to draw more attention to this question. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/30870143)